# Couchbase Lite 1.1.0-31 LiveQuery Has All Rows But All Documents NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, couchbase, couchbase-lite

been loving using Couchbase in my iOS and Android projects to create Couch documents and replicate them to remote servers. Unfortunately I've run in to a bit of a snag recently since updating to the newest version of Couchbase Lite.

Before my most recent update, I would set up my manager and database and then call `initializeQuery` the following would have pulled all the docs from the db with their data intact where I could see the documentID and data in each doc (double checking the database I see all the docs are still there and they all have the key `type` set with a string): (Code posted in Objective C, though seeing similar results with Swift/Android)

```
 - (void) initializeQuery {
     CBLQuery* query = [_database createAllDocumentsQuery];
     liveQuery = query.asLiveQuery;
     [liveQuery addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"rows" options: 0 context: NULL];
     [liveQuery start];
 }

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
     if (object == liveQuery) {

         CBLQueryEnumerator *result = liveQuery.rows;

         NSLog(@"No. 1 - number of rows is %lu", (unsigned long)result.count);

         for (CBLQueryRow *row in result) {
              NSLog(@"No. 2 - what is each row's doc ID: %@", row.documentID);
              NSLog(@"No. 3 - what is each row's document %@", row.document);
         }
     }
 }
```

Now (since updating to the newest Couchbase Lite) I still get the correct number of rows (on NSLog No. 1), and get all the right docIds (on NSLog No. 2) but each row's document is now `(null)` (on NSLog No. 3) and all keys/values do not exist. Can anyone explain to me if I need to change something to get my data to remain intact all the way to the end. If so a poor Idaho programmer will owe you a life debt! (Not worth much it is true, but it is all I have to give)

Answer (score 0):

This error only appeared to happen with allDocument, asynchronous queries and was previously found and addressed by the Couchbase Lite devs here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/755 and was fixed in build 1.1.1, available here: http://latestbuilds.hq.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite-ios/release/1.1.1/

So if you see this issue check for an update and move from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1. After doing so everything is puppies, unicorns and rainbows!